# RegisterType results in an error

Tags: c#, unity-container

Hi I am trying to set up a testing project in order to pratis a bit of Unit Testing while using Unity IoC container and Moq.

I seem to be getting an error when I try to register a type in Unity.This is my code:

```
public static class SetupMockObjects
{
    public static IProductRepository GetProductRepository() {
        Mock<IProductRepository> productRepository = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
        productRepository.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(new List<Product> { 
            new Product { Name = "Football" , Price = 25 },
            new Product { Name = "Surf board" , Price = 179 },
            new Product { Name = "Running shoes" , Price = 95 }
        });

        return productRepository.Object;
    }
}

public static void Initialise()
{
    var container = BuildUnityContainer();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
}

private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
{
     var container = new UnityContainer();
     container.RegisterType<IProductRepository , SetupMockObjects.GetProductRepository()>();
     return container;
}
```

Now I am creating a mock object here only because I do not want to create a data access layer so I figured it would be easier just to create a mock object.

The problem is inside BuildUnityContainer() method when I try to register a type I get this errors:

```
Error   1   Invalid expression term ',' 
Error   2   ; expected  
Error   3   ; expected  
Error   4   Invalid expression term ')' 
Error   5   ) expected
```

I am prety sure that I am calling RegisterType with the right generic parameters thats why I do not understand why are these errors thrown.Where have I made the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use `SetupMockObjects.GetProductRepository()` as a type argument. That's not going to work - type arguments have to be the names of types (or type parameters). I suspect you meant to use it as a regular argument:

```
container.RegisterInstance<IProductRepository>(SetupMockObjects.GetProductRepository());
```

Or perhaps more readably:

```
var repository = SetupMockObjects.GetProductRepository();
container.RegisterInstance<IProductRepository>(repository);
```

Or if type inference works (I don't have the docs in front of me to check the declaration) you could just use:

```
container.RegisterInstance(SetupMockObjects.GetProductRepository());
```

After all, the return type of the method is the same as the type argument you want to specify.

Note that I've changed the call from `RegisterType` to `RegisterInstance` as you're just trying to bind an interface to a specific instance.